Is G/cm³ a Unit of Specific Weight? Clarifying Conversion from N/m³ and Potential Confusion with Density

I was working on a physics assignment and previously gave density values in g/cm³. Now, continuing with the report, I am wondering if G/cm³ which is given in the box under specific weight can be used as a unit for specific gravity, or maybe my instructor confused it with density.

Without more information, it's hard to know what your instructor thinks.  Specific weight does indeed have units of $\text{N/m}^3$;  and it's not the same thing as density, though they are related by a factor of $g$.  It's not clear to me what the notation "[G/cm^3]" might mean.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The symbol for grams is $g$, never $G$.

Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately we don't have a range of information from the instructor that will help with this problem.
I'm wondering if it's just written as a gram-force/centimeter^3 unit.
The next task also has the unit kG/m^3.
And I doubt that this is where we are supposed to give the density, because earlier we have to fill in the density field separately where the unit is written correctly i.e. g/cm^3 or kg/m^3 (with lowercase letters).

g/cm^3 (lower case g) is a standard unit of specific gravity.  Note that the specific gravity of pure water is 1.0 g/cm^3.

Mass density = mass/volume
\begin{align}
\rho=\frac{m}{V}\rightarrow\text{gram/cm$^3$}
\end{align}
"Weight" density = weight/volume
\begin{align}
\hat{\rho}=\frac{mg}{V}\rightarrow\text{Newton/cm$^3$}
\end{align}
